# Generate bound for layer group with REST API

Tags: geoserver-rest-api

Using the

```
geoserver/rest/workspaces/{workspace}/datastores/{datastore}/layergroups/
```

to generate the Layergroups.

How can we generate the bounds for the layer group through API?

```
 "bounds": {
            "minx": -82.64339598999999,
            "maxx": -82.20550036099996,
            "miny": 27.03191051400006,
            "maxy": 27.554046017000076,
            "crs": "EPSG:4326"
        },
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: In general the bounds of a layer group will be the union of the bounds of the layers in the group